# android stagefright unit and integration testing for codecs

Tags: android, unit-testing

I need to do testings on android platform on a new codec integrated to stagefright framework using omx calls.

I had some questions on this below:

1. can I do testings at each framework level(i.e, omx+codec alone, omx+stagefright, omx+stagefright+mediaplayer)
2. Is there any testapps provided on each layers to do testings unit level and then integration testing and overall system testing.
3. I heard about robolectric tool which does unit level testing, CTS for system level .does it can meet my requirement?
4. robolectric, android test framework, robotium, junittests, CTS, uiautomator tools i have found in search, does any one having experience on these can tell that my requirement can do?

Thanks in advance,

Vinay